# Subsection as part of the left column

Tags: tabu, scrartcl

I would like to have subsection titles be part of a table so that the output is something like this

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu}{p{5cm} p{5cm}}
   \textbf{Subsection Title}  &  \begin{tabu}{ll}
                                 a  &  B  \\  
                                 a  &  B  \\  
                                 C  & D 
                              \end{tabu}
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

So the subsection would be be in the first column and then in the right column I would like to have either another table or just some text. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you need the tabu package? Tabu is buggy and unmaintained. See the readme here github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu.

Comment: Could you add some background information on the intedned use of such a table?

Comment: @albert Sorry, it doesn't have to be tabu

Comment: @leandriis I guess I could also do it by defining a new command. I just thought for the structure it would make more sense to have it as a section. The documents has very short subsections like this. But, yeah, it is probably easier to just define a new command.